# flutter TabBarView sometimes not triggering on gesture swipe

Tags: flutter, tabs, swipe

I am using Flutter -Android studio. I have main screen with TabBarView control (2 pages). each page get data from sqfite database. both have same statefull widget class, but I pass parameter to look into database and display.
Issue : when I click tabbar header , data displayed is Ok. But when I swipe tabs, it sometimes work and sometimes does not work. as per below video. I have check and seems that Build event is not trigger every if Swipe was done.
Main widget with tabbarview

[screen record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anGQK.gif)

> > Note that 1st tab has only 1 record, while second has 6 records. tabClick works fine, but swipe sometime not work properly.

```
body: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: [
      DisplayTransactions(
        tmptransType: TransactionType.enIncome,
        transacBloc: _transacBloc,
        SelectedItemsCount: bRowSelectionCount,
        onSelectionChanged: (count) {
          setState(() {
            bRowSelectionCount = count;
          });
        },
      ),
      // Center(child: Text("Page 1")),
      DisplayTransactions(
        tmptransType: TransactionType.enExpense,
        transacBloc: _transacBloc,
        SelectedItemsCount: bRowSelectionCount,
        onSelectionChanged: (count) {
          setState(() {
            bRowSelectionCount = count;
          });
        },
        //Center(child: Text("Page 2")),
      )
    ],
  ),
```

------ > Widget to display data into listview for each tabbar page

```
class DisplayTransactions extends StatefulWidget {
final TransactionType tmptransType;
final FinanceTransBlock transacBloc;
final Function onSelectionChanged;
int SelectedItemsCount;

/// -1 expense  1 income
DisplayTransactions(
{Key key,
@required this.tmptransType,
@required this.transacBloc,
this.SelectedItemsCount,
this.onSelectionChanged})
: super(key: key);

@override
_DisplayTransactionsState createState() => _DisplayTransactionsState();
}

class _DisplayTransactionsState extends State<DisplayTransactions> {
var isSelected = false;
var mycolor = Colors.white;

// int iselectionCount = 0;


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
widget.transacBloc.transacType = widget.tmptransType;
debugPrint("----------------------------- ${widget.tmptransType}");
if (widget.SelectedItemsCount == 0) {// if no rows selected, then reload database based on trans type, eg expense, or income.. etc
widget.transacBloc.refresh();
}

return StreamBuilder<List<FinanceTransaction>>(
stream: widget.transacBloc.transacations,
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.hasData) {
List<FinanceTransaction> list = snapshot.data;
// return  buildTaskListWal(snapshot.data);
return Padding(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the app is taking some time to retrieve the new data.  Try checking for null on the snapshot.data and display a circularProgressIndicator.

```
if (snapshot.data == null) {
  return CirgularProgressIndicator();
 } else {
//display data
}
```

Comment: I am already doing this step into  this step  >>>> if (snapshot.hasData) { } else {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );

Comment: hasData is kind of useless.  It could set to true, even if the data property has no data, yet.  I've run into this many times, now I always check if snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.length == 0.

Comment: not working. I used  if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.length == 0) {  >> not working.

Comment: Strange thing I noticed , the build widget is not triggered. I placed a debugPrint into the  _DisplayTransactionsState extends State  .. class, and I noticed the android studio RUN window. the debugPrint text is not triggered each time  when swipe >> so the Build widget is not triggered. that is why data is not updated.      Question : why DisplayTransaction is not called upon tap swipe ? .. this check is done into above code at below line                                                                         debugPrint("----------------------------- ${widget.tmptransType}");

Comment: If you wait a second between swipes, does it display properly?